# Is an Avatar all-knowing?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, rama, avatars, epics

e.g., do Shri Ram/ Shri Krishna know everything that is going to happen (even in their material forms) and do their leelas to teach lessons to us?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a partial answer to this question.

Bhagavan Sri Krishna is all-knowing, as mentioned at many places by Adi Shankaracharya in his Bhagavad Gita Bhashya. Below are four instances (source: gita supersite, translations by Swami Gambhirananda).

[BG bhashya 3.3](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=3&field_nsutra_value=3&scsh=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&choose=1)

> ।3.3।। लोके अस्मिन् शास्त्रार्थानुष्ठानाधिकृतानां त्रैवर्णिकानां द्विविधा द्विप्रकारा निष्ठा स्थितिः अनुष्ठेयतात्पर्यं पुरा पूर्वं सर्गादौ प्रजाः सृष्ट्वा तासाम् अभ्युदयनिःश्रेयसप्राप्तिसाधनं वेदार्थसंप्रदायमाविष्कुर्वता प्रोक्ता **मया सर्वज्ञेन ईश्वरेण** हे अनघ अपाप।....

> 3.3 Anagha, O unblemished one, O sinless one; [This word of address suggests that Arjuna is alified to receive the Lord's instruction.] dvividha, two kinds of ; nistha, steadfastness, persistence in what is undertaken; asmin loke, in this world, for the people of the three castes who are alified for following the scriptures; prokta, were spoken of; **maya, by Me (Krishna), the omniscient God**, who had revealed for them the traditional teachings of the Vedas, which are the means of securing prosperity and the highest Goal; pura, in the days of yore, in the beginning the creation, after having brought into being the creatures.

[BG bhashya 3.30](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=3&field_nsutra_value=30&scsh=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&choose=1)

> ।3.30।। **मयि वासुदेवे परमेश्वरे सर्वज्ञे** सर्वात्मनि सर्वाणि कर्माणि संन्यस्य निक्षिप्य अध्यात्मचेतसा विवेकबुद्ध्या अहं कर्ता ईश्वराय भृत्यवत् करोमि इत्यनया बुद्ध्या।....

> ....mayi, to **Me, who am Vasudeva, the omniscient supreme Lord**, the Self of all;

[BG bhashya 7.6](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=7&field_nsutra_value=6&scsh=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&choose=1)

> ।।7.6) एतद्योनीनि एते परापरे क्षेत्रक्षेत्रज्ञलक्षणे प्रकृती योनिः येषां भूतानां तानि एतद्योनीनि भूतानि सर्वाणि इति एवम् उपधारय जानीहि। यस्मात् मम प्रकृती योनिः कारणं सर्वभूतानाम् अतः अहं कृत्स्नस्य समस्तस्य जगतः प्रभवः उत्पत्तिः प्रलयः विनाशः तथा। प्रकृतिद्वयद्वारेण **अहं सर्वज्ञः ईश्वरः** जगतः कारणमित्यर्थः।।यतः तस्मात्

> ....The meaning is this: **I (Krishna), who am the ominscient God**, am the source of the Univese through My two Prakrtis....

[BG bhashya 7.22](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=7&field_nsutra_value=22&scsh=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&choose=1)

> ।।7.22।। स तया मद्विहितया श्रद्धया युक्तः सन् तस्याः देवतातन्वाः राधनम् आराधनम् ईहते चेष्टते। लभते च ततः तस्याः आराधितायाः देवतातन्वाः कामान् ईप्सितान् **मयैव परमेश्वरेण सर्वज्ञेन** कर्मफलविभागज्ञतया

> ...maya eva, by **Me (Krishna) alone, who am the omniscient, supreme God,** because I am possessed of the knowledge of the apportionment of the results of actions.

Comment: Shri Krishna does seem to be all knowing. He sees things happening elsewhere and things yet to happen and converses with celestial beings, shows his divine form, etc. Not many such instances in the case of Shri Ram.

Comment: @SatwikAgrawal Sri Ram is a big mystery. Either he was genuinely not all-knowing, or he tricked the entire humanity into believing that he was an ordinary man.

Comment: Yes. In whole of Ramayan he hardly accepts he's Vishnu. The only expose is fight with Parashuram. Hence although it's well known that he was only doing Maya, it's difficult to prove because it's hardly admitted.